# Gulp: File not able to read which was created in last task

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

Here `app/folder1/` is containing **3 angularjs files (controller, service, factory)**. By using `'task1'`, I am combining all html files into **'templates.js'**. In `'task2'`, I need to combine 3 angularjs files and 1 templates.js file into single file.

But in 'task2', system is reading only 3 angularjs files. If i run 'task2' separately then system is combining 4 files.

```
gulp.task('task1',function() {
     gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
           .pipe(minifyHtml({empty: true}))
           .on('error', gutil.log)
           .pipe(templateCache({root: 'app/folder1/',module:'myModule'}))
           .on('error', gutil.log)
           .pipe(gulp.dest('app/folder2/'))
           .on('error', gutil.log);
     });
});

gulp.task('task2',function(){
     var newName = 'script_' + new Date().getTime() + '.js';
     gulp.src('app/folder2/**/*.js')
         .on('error', gutil.log)
         .pipe(concat(newName,{newLine: ';'}))
         .on('error', gutil.log)
         .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/'))
         .on('error', gutil.log)
         .pipe(uglify({mangle:false }))
         .on('error', gutil.log)
         .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/'))
         .on('error', gutil.log);
    });
});


gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence('task1','task2',callback);
});
```

If i run `gulp` command it is not combining **templates.js** file.

If i run `gulp`, `gulp task2` then it is working as expected.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to return the stream if you're not going to handle the `callback` within `task1` and `task2`.

```
return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
         .pipe(...
```

Comment: Yep, otherwise, gulp can't effectively tell if the stream has finished processing, even with the sequence.